# M48Z02 (16Kbit ZEROPOWER SRAM) is TTL compatible?

Tags: cmos, ttl, standard, sram

I've some problem using together **TLL** and **CMOS** integrated. I'm developing a project and only now I discovered that the two standards can create troubles together.

So I decided to **use only TTL chips**. Luckily I can also use HCT integrated, that are bot compatible with TTL and CMOS.

I'm not sure about compatibility only about one chip... the **M48Z02** ([datasheet](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00000524.pdf)). It is a 5V, 16 Kbit ZEROPOWER SRAM. In the datasheet it is also written:

> Pin and function compatible with JEDEC standard 2 K x 8 SRAMs

Does it mean something about the compatibility with TTL technology?

If not, where can I find information about the compatibility between M48Z02 and TTL technology?

Any help you can provide will be really appreciated.

Comment: TTL is about logic levels. So look what voltages the part is working with and decide.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you, should I delete this answer or if you want, put an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: It's up to you. If you can compose a good answer yourself, such that people could benefit from it in the future - do it. Or wait for someone to come up with such an answer. Or just wait for upvotes/downvotes to see if people find this question useful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Eugene Sh.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/58132/eugene-sh) said, TTL/CMOS problem is about logic level.

If fact the two different technologies use different voltage level to send logic high signal (1) or low signal (0).

Here an image (from [allaboutcircuits.com](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-3/logic-signal-voltage-levels/)) that can explain this concept:

[image: acceptable TTL gate input/output signal level]

In the M48Z02 datasheet  it is written:

```
|      Parameter      |  Min  |   Max   | Unit |
------------------------------------------------
| Input low voltage   | –0.3  |   0.8   |  V   |
| Input high voltage  |  2.2  | Vcc+0.3 |  V   |
| Output low voltage  |       |   0.4   |  V   |
| Output high voltage |  2.4  |         |  V   |
```

Putting data together, during communication from a TTL chip to M48Z02:

1. TTL -> M48Z02:

   - Logic 0: communication ok, 0 > –0.3 and 0.5 < 0.8
   - Logic 1: communication ok, 2.7 > 2.2 and 5 < Vcc+0.3

During communication from M48Z02 to TTL:

2. M48Z02 -> TTL:

   - Logic 0: communication ok, 0.4 < 0.8
   - Logic 1: communication ok, 2.4 > 2

**In conclusion, they can communicate correctly.**